# Why are both `do` ... `end` and `end` style blocks valid for `while` and `for` loops?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Why are both of these styles valid? Are they different at a fundamental level?

```
while true do
  puts "I am awesome"
end

while true
  puts "I am awesome"
end

for i in 1..6 do
  puts i
end

for i in 1..6
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while` and `for` are not methods but are keywords, and the related constructions are built-in into Ruby. The part that follows them may look similar to a block, but is not a block. Since it is not a block, there is no need for `do`, but people may accidentally write `do` due to the similarity of this construction to a block. So by design, the `do` keyword is made optional in these constructions.

Comment: I understand they are not methods, since they are not in Object, but i was asking why it exists the way it does ?

Comment: [The `do` keyword is optional.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop)

Answer (score 1):

You have to have *some* way to tell Ruby that the condition ends and the loop begins. And Ruby allows you tell it two different ways: using the keyword `do` or using an expression separator (`;` or newline). So, all of the following are equivalent:

```
while true do puts "I am awesome" end

while true; puts "I am awesome" end

while true
  puts "I am awesome" end
```

Using *both* the keyword *and* an expression separator is redundant, but not harmful, so why should it be an error? It's like telling Ruby "The condition ends here. No, really, the condition ends here!"

It's *exactly* the same as with conditionals:

```
if true then 1 else 0 end

if true; 1 else 0 end

if true
  1 else 0 end
```

Or even method definitions:

```
def foo() 'foo' end

def foo; 'foo' end

def foo
  'foo' end
```